# Reify arbitrary data-kind to a (compile-time known) value

Tags: haskell, ghc, data-kinds, derivingvia

I want to be able to write something like:

```hs
reify (Proxy @True)) == True;
reify (Proxy @(Just 5)) == Just 5;
```

Is it possible by a blanket implementation? I got as far as

```hs
class Reify (a :: k) where
  reify :: Proxy a -> k
```

And I have no idea how to write this except than writing every instance by hand: one instance for True, one instance for False, etc. I don't want to write it all by hand, and I don't want to use template haskell to do it for me. Can I have just one instance to do it?

Or maybe there exists some other approach? The use-case for me is to be able to write:

```
type DeriveHelper :: Settings -> Type -> Type
newtype DeriveHelper s a = DeriveHelper a

instance (Generic a, GMyClass (Rep a)) => MyClass (DeriveHelper s a) where
  myMethod (DeriveHelper x) = genericMyMethod (reify (Proxy @s)) $ from x

-- and then
data FooBar ...
  deriving MyClass via DeriveHelper SomeSettings FooBar
```

As for the libraries I've seen in the world that do this, they seem to all have small Settings which I believe is reified by hand.

Comment: This seems to be one more question whose answer is [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah, that was my last resort. I believe you can't (with convenience) use singletones without template haskell, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

I would be remiss if I didn't note that the best solution at the moment is still the `singletons` package, which provides the `demote` function to do what you want (see example at the end).  However, that implementation uses Template Haskell internally to lift existing `Prelude` types and requires you to use TH explicitly to lift additional types.  And, you said you didn't want to do that...

So, I guess it's technically possible with generics.  You can use `Data.Typeable` or `Type.Reflection` to destruct the type-level `t` of kind `k`, and then construct a *term* `t` of *type* `k` using `GHC.Generics` (or `Data.Data` or whatever).

Consider the following proof of concept which uses `Data.Typeable` for type destruction and `Data.Data` for term construction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Reify where

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data

demote :: forall k t. (Typeable t, Data k) => Proxy (t :: k) -> k
demote pxy
  = let rep = typeRep pxy
    in  fromConstr $ mkConstr (dataTypeOf @k undefined)
                              (removeTick $ tyConName . typeRepTyCon $ rep)
                              []
                              Prefix
  where removeTick ('\'':xs) = xs
```

This is only a partial implementation, but it will demote arbitrary nullary prefix constructors:

```
data MyType = A | B Int deriving (Show, Data)

main = do
    print $ (demote (Proxy @'Nothing) :: Maybe Int)
    print $ (demote (Proxy @'False) :: Bool)
    print $ (demote (Proxy @'A) :: MyType)
```

I don't see any technical barrier to generalizing it to handling constructors of arbitrary arity and adding support for `Int#`, etc.

Maybe someone's implemented this in a package somewhere, but I don't know where.

Anyway, the `singletons` solution using TH is ready-to-run and would look something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Reify where

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Kind
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.Natural

-- define a new type supporting "demote"
$(singletons [d|
  data MyType = A | B Bool deriving (Show)
  |])

-- add "demote" support to an existing type (e.g., imported from a library)
data LibraryType = C | D Bool deriving (Show)
$(genSingletons [''LibraryType])

main = do
  print $ (demote @('Just 5) :: Maybe Natural)
  print $ (demote @'False :: Bool)
  print $ (demote @'A :: MyType)
  print $ (demote @('D 'False) :: LibraryType)
```

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks. I've never had a chance to look into Data.Data before